# On succesfull log in should I save user data In Sessions, global variables or query on every page?

Tags: php

If I have an authentication system with user name and password, that queries data from the data base on log in, like user name, user id, profile description, etc. How should I save this data so I can show it on every page, for example if I want to show the user name on the navigation bar on every page as long as the user is logged in.

Should I save the user id in a session and use it to query the user data on every page in order to show the user data on that page ?

```
login.php
Query the users table to get the user id based on user name and password
SELECT uId FROM user WHERE pass = $_POST['pass'] and name = $_POST['name'];

$_SESSION['userId'] = $res['uid'];

otherPages.php
SELECT user_name FROM users WHERE uid = $_SESSION['userId'];
```

Should I query this info only once when the log in happened and save everything in sessions ?

```
login.php
Query the users table to get the user id based on user name and password
SELECT * FROM user WHERE pass = $_POST['pass'] and name = $_POST['name'];

$_SESSION['userId'] = $res['uid'];
$_SESSION['name'] = $res['user_name'];
$_SESSION['description'] = $res['des'];

otherPages.php
echo $_SESSION['name'];
```

What is the best way to keep user data between pages after log in ? querying on every page works well until now but it feels redundant. How is this usually handled ? Thank you.

*all queries in this question are purely for example, the code that I actually use is well formatted :) (probably).*

*Passwords are also hashed using php password_hash();*

Comment: Passwords in plain text?? No no

Comment: @Akintunde-Rotimi They are hashed, this is just for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This purely depends on your needs. If you know that the user data can be changed externally e.g. by another user, event,.. then you should fetch the data from database every time to keep them updated. However if the only one who can modify the data is user itself, then you can safely keep this info in session and it MIGHT help your application. It doesn't really matter which one you choose as the time difference will be minor.

EDIT:
Also, you should identify user by his username only.